# The formula expression is invalid: Syntax error. Missing ')' Help Please

Tags: formula, formula-field

When trying to save the below formula I get this error:

> The formula expression is invalid: Syntax error. Missing ')' Help Please

Why do I get this error? How can I fix it?

```
AND(
          IF ( ISBLANK( [Case].ContactId) , false,
          AND( ![Case].Contact.CSATOptOut__c,
                   OR( ISNULL(Contact.CSAT_Date__c ), true,
                   Contact.CSAT_Date__c  <= TODAY() -5 ),              
                   OR(
                       RecordTypeId = 0128E0000009Fd5QAE,
                       ISPICKVAL( Origin, "Telefon", "Chat" )
                   ),
                   ISBLANK( Contact.MemberInGroup__c, false ),
                   ISPICKVAL( Status, "Avslutat" ),
                   OwnerId <= "NatterBox",
                   OwnerId <= "API-User Api-User",
                   NOT( ISPICKVAL( CaseReason, "Inget svar" )),
                   Contact.CreatedDate <= NOW()       
          )
        )
        )
```

Comment: Wait, is this a formula in `Process Builder` or a `Forumula Field`?

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few errors in your formula

- You are not passing the second parameter for the `AND` operator. `AND` operator needs at least 2 values. (Top most `AND`)
- You are using `ISPICKVAL` with 3 parameters whereas it takes only two
- You are comparing `OwnerId` field with `<=` operator, I think it should be either `==` or `!=`
- `OwnerId` is the Id field, so it will contain the Id and not `Name`, rather you will have to compare with `Owner.Name`
- You are missing the quotes on RecordTypeId

The error you are getting is because of the first point i.e. if you don't have anything else to pass to `AND` operator, remove that operator or else pass the other value.

On solving this issue, you will get the remaining errors which I mentioned above which will help you fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the quotes around your record type id and your external AND operator needs at least another value. 
Anyway there are many others syntax error.

ISNULL and ISBLANK functions return a boolean, then it's not correct to write:

```
ISNULL(Contact.CSAT_Date__c ), true
```

but only

```
ISNULL(Contact.CSAT_Date__c )
```

Other errors is that you are passing more then one value to ISPICKVAL function and that you're comparing a string (OwnerId) with the <= operator.

Try the above formula and edit per your needs:

```
IF(
        ISBLANK(ContactId),
        AND(
            CSATOptOut__c,
            OR(
                ISNULL(Contact.CSAT_Date__c),
                Contact.CSAT_Date__c  <= (TODAY()-5)
            ),
            OR(
                RecordTypeId = 0128E0000009Fd5QAE,
                ISPICKVAL( Origin, "Telefon"),
                ISPICKVAL( Origin, "Chat")
            ),
            ISBLANK( Contact.MemberInGroup__c ),
            ISPICKVAL( Status, "Avslutat" ),
            NOT( ISPICKVAL( CaseReason, "Inget svar" )),
            Contact.CreatedDate <= NOW()  
        )
    )
```

I would also suggest to check the logic of your formula and to use the Record Type Developer Name instead of the Id.